# What are they patenting on this product

Tags: scope

In reference to the patent: [WO2017024291A3](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2017024291A3)

Answer (score 1):

As you just found, using www.google.com/patents is unreliable when searching patents. You can find a better version at [patents.google.com](https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2017024291A2/en) and even better at [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/WO_2017_024291_A2). In any case, this is a patent application (not yet a patent) and it is for a children's play fort that floats on a cushion of air. Please see the figure below from the patent. Also, you used the tag "design-patent", but this is not a design patent, but a utility patent application.

[image]